# Can't get Kotlin classes in Java maven project to work (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, kotlin

I've got a maven (DropWizard) java project. I'd really like to add some Kotlin classes, but seem unable to do so. In my real project I've added the maven configuration like https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#compiling-kotlin-and-java-sources, but my Kotlin classes aren't seen by the 'normal' java code. Neither by maven nor by Eclipse.

So I tried the mixed-source example https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/maven/mixed-code-hello-world. That worked in Maven, but still not in Eclipse.

What am I missing here?

[image: This is my workspace]

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there are several issues.

Eclipse doesn't recognize `src/main/kotlin` as source directory. To fix it, please add the directory to the classpath manually: properties for mixed-code-hello-world -> Java Build Path -> Source tab -> Add Folder...

Then, try to Remove and Add Kotlin Nature to reindex Kotlin files in the project. To do this, press right-click on the project -> Configure Kotlin -> Remove Kotlin Nature.[image: Kotlin Configuration]

I've created tickets for these problems:

1. [Eclipse does not recognize kotlin source directory](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16540)
2. [Kotlin plugin does not reindex files after adding source directory](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16541)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it does not seem to help.

Comment: After running Maven > update project, the Kotlin nature is back and the kotlin_bin is empty.

Comment: Just to be clear: you've removed and then added Kotlin nature? If it doesn't help, try to rebuild project (Project -> Clean)

Comment: did all of that, to no avail.

Comment: This is not my main problem. The main problem is that my standard java project is not building when I'm using Maven, which is stopping my progress all together.

Comment: Just for clarification, in the Java Build Path, I added the kotlin source, but I DID NOT change the Default output folder (my-project/target/classes). Then I first removed the kotlin nature, then added the kotlin nature, then clean build the project and the problem was gone.